# What is meant module in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, module

I want to understand the meaning of modules since when I started out learning node.js all tutorials started out by using modules like http, fs etc. I want to understand what it is, why we use it I have seen many javascript tutorials but they never told us about modules.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the word "modules" refers to small units of independent, reusable code. They are the foundation of many JavaScript design patterns and are critically necessary when building any non-trivial JavaScript-based application.

The closest analog in the Java language are Java Classes. However, JavaScript modules export a value, rather than define a type. In practice, most JavaScript modules export an object literal, a function, or a constructor. Modules that export a string containing an HTML template or a CSS stylesheet are also common.

Look up https://spring.io/understanding/javascript-modules

Answer (score 0):

Modules are just a collection of code designed to perform a certain functionality (like C/C++ packages, python modules, and so). When you import a module onto your code, you are essentially just importing a codebase written by someone else to perform a task that would have been complex to implement yourself.